Switch between multiple popup windows with win_gotoid()
I create two popup windows and want to switch between them, but win_gotoid fails. The code below should be a minimal example of the problem I'm running into.
vim9script

g:pop_a = 0
g:pop_b = 0

export def ShowDualPopups(a_lines: list<string>, b_lines: list<string>)
    g:pop_a = popup_create(a_lines, {
        col: 10,
        cursorline: true,
        filter: (id, key) => {
            if key == 'l'
                win_gotoid(g:pop_b)
                return true
            endif
            return id->popup_filter_menu(key)
        }})
    g:pop_b = popup_create(b_lines, {
        col: 40,
        cursorline: true,
        filter: (id, key) => {
            if key == 'h'
                win_gotoid(g:pop_a) # THIS RETURNS FALSE
                return true
            endif
            return id->popup_filter_menu(key)
        }})
enddef

var lines_a = 'this goes in the left window'->split(' ')
var lines_b = 'this goes in the right window'->split(' ')

command! ShowDualPopups ShowDualPopups(lines_a, lines_b)
nnoremap <leader>p :ShowDualPopups<cr>

The code above creates two popup windows side-by-side. Since the second window is created later, it is the 'active' window and its filter is able to consume keystrokes while the first popup is doing nothing. But win_gotoid(g:pop_a) returns false, failing to go to the other popup.
What's the cause of this behavior, and is there another better way to switch between popups?

I don't think that you can use win_gotoid() with popup windows, and there doesn't appear to be a popup_* equivalent.

In Vim popup can never become an active window. Instead it installs a filter function that intercepts key press before any active window sees it.
If you have several popups shown at the same time then one having the highest zindex has priority over others.
To change popup's settings after it has been created use :h popup_setoptions().

Thank, adjusting the zindex solves my problem.

The popup cannot have the keyboard focus:
The popup window contains a buffer, and that buffer is always associated with
the popup window. The window cannot be in Normal, Visual or Insert mode, it
does not get keyboard focus.

More information with :help E366
